# Implement non-persistent data storage with data structures in Javascript

Tags: javascript, data-structure

For one of my projects, I am required not to use a database to store data in memory. Instead, I must use data structures for that.

I tried to search the web but can't find good ressources that help to do that.

Data I have to handle are api endpoints. How can deal with it?

Comment: Almost anything you can think of can be modeled with JavaScript's array and object. Really, a `let database = {}` is all you need. If you explain more about how your data looks like I can try posting an answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
As an example I want to create a new user via a sign up form. I have input firstname, lastname and email. Then the user clicks register button to sign up. How can I save this data with data structure (and not dbms)?

Answer (score 1):

So this answer is based on your comment. Think of it this way, you have three pieces of information which are `name value` pairs. For example:

```
firstName: Jon,
lastName: Doe,
email: jdoe@cloud.com
```

So turning this into an object in JavaScript is literally:

```
let user = {
  firstName: 'Jon',
  lastName: 'Doe',
  email: 'jdoe@cloud.com'
}
```

Now you want to save it to your database:

```
let db = {};
db['user'] = user;

console.log(db);

// prints
{
  user: {
    firstName: 'Jon',
    lastName: 'Doe',
    email: 'jdoe@cloud.com'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for `state management`. An interesting article: https://codeburst.io/state-management-in-javascript-15d0d98837e1

Some very well know libraries that help you are [Redux](https://redux.js.org/) and [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/).